# In ubuntu 23.04 wifi is not working but bluetooth is working

Tags: ubuntu, connection, wifi, adapter

Suddenly after an update my wifi is stopped working but my bluetooth is working fine in ubuntu 23.04. Previously it was working before the update. After every restart wifi gets connected and after 10-15 seconds its gets dis connected and prompt a message connection failed activation of network connection failed. My laptop wifi chipset is realtek rtl8852be wifi 6 802.11ax pcie adapter. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

tried nothing and expecting that my wifi should work properly.